# simple jquery question

Tags: javascript

I have the following HTML.

```
<input type="text" class="embeddedLabel" />
```

And I wish to tie a function to the focus event of the textbox with...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(input[@class = 'embeddedLabel'].focus(function(){
        alert('embeddedLabel textbox found');
    });
};
```

However, I can't make this work.  The alert never fires when I click in the textbox.  Is it obvious to anyone what the issue is here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing some quotes:

```
$("input[@class = 'embeddedLabel']")
```

Comment: I was missing the quotes as well as a paren on the end of the expression.  Thx for the tip...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready
(
    $(input[@class = 'embeddedLabel']).bind("focus",function(){
        alert('embeddedLabel textbox found');
    });
};
```